# API access issue in Flutter

Tags: http, flutter, dart

I am trying to make a GET request on an API but it is giving **error 400** although I tried everything, if I try the similar URL and auth_key using postman it gets the required output.
I think it might be an issue of some HOST as in postman the host is also present in headers.

```
Future<String> getJsonData() async{

    var response = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull(url),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'ApiKey'}
    );

    if(response.statusCode != 200){
      return "failed";
    }

    setState((){
      var convertData = json.decode(response.body);
      var temp = convertData["objects"] as List;

      data = temp.map<Detail>((json) => Detail.fromJson(json)).toList();
    });

    print(data.length);
    return "Success";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check it `'Authorization': 'ApiKey'` you must give a String **key** not string "ApiKey"

Comment: Yes I added the actual api key only.